# Need Mindterm Equivalent for Android Lollipop

Tags: android, sftp

..As we all know, plain java JARs will not run on Android. Android Lollipop further restricts java JARs in that they have to be position independant.

The Mindterm SSH/SFTP client is one of my most important apps, because it is intuitive and because its SFTP plugin runs AFTER one has logged into SSH, thereby eliminating the 'Received message too long' error.

As Mindterm has not (yet) been recompiled for Android Lollipop and later, I am looking for an alternative. No, not one of the dozen SSH/SFTP apps in the stores that don't work because they don't handle the SFTP 'message too long' error. I need an equivalent that behaves just like Mindterm.

Any ideas? Thanx